# PHP with unserialize function doesn't work

Tags: php, function, serialization, echo

I have a problem with the `unserialize()` function. The problem in mine opinion is in this line:

```
$rslt = unserialize($data);
```

and doesn't echo this command:

```
echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];
```

What is the problem?

```
<?php
// *****************zima user id********************
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');

// *****************zima product id i pravi session********************

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("shopping_katalog") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM x9qg6_jshopping_cart_temp WHERE id_cookie ='".$_COOKIE["jshopping_temp_cart"]."'");    
$data=null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data = $row['cart'];
}
$rslt = unserialize($data);
echo $data;

$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('kor', $usr_id);
$session->set('kupid', $rslt[0]["product_id"]);
echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];
$mymessage = $session->get('mymessage');
echo $mymessage;

if (!$result) {
echo 'Проблем со купувањето _php.' . mysql_error();
exit;
}else{
}
```

The text that I'm trying to read with the `unserialize()` function is this:

```
a:1:{i:4;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"209";s:5:"price";d:1;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:12:"product_name";s:4:"test";s:11:"thumb_image";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}}
```

Comment: There's a missing double quote in `mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass)`. Could this be your problem?

Comment: That's way too much code. You should reduce it to the smallest sample that still reproduces your problem.

Comment: Do you really want to `unserialize` the last row from the database only?

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. What do you get back from `unserialize()`? What does `$data` contain?

Comment: @Pekka $data contains this data:  a:1:{i:4;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"209";s:5:"price";d:1;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:12:"product_name";s:4:"test";s:11:"thumb_image";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}}

Comment: @Pekka and i'm trying to get product_id - the number 5196

Comment: Since typos cannot be produced by copy&pasting, I don't trust you this is the real code.

Comment: What result do you get back from `unserialize()`?

Comment: @Pekka nothing... that is the problem :)

Comment: According to the manual, `unserialize()` returns `false` if it fails to unserialize the data it has been given. If that is the case, then something is wrong with that data. How / where are you serializing it?

Comment: "The converted value is returned, and can be a boolean, integer, float, string, array or object.  In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued."  I got an error message telling me to look at offset 76 or there about.  Copied I got something like `s:??3:"209"` and those ?? were at fault.  Encoding issue?  What goes into DB is not what comes out?

Comment: Ok so I could unserialize the text given in the original description and I could parse the 'product_id'. But instead of position 0 in the array its at position 4. Try $rslt[4]['product_id']. Also, please check how you serialize your data. This is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `'product_id'` value has a `[4]` index key `'a:1:{i:4;...'` 
Try:

```
echo $rslt[4]['product_id'];
```

Comment: Can u help me and tell me how can I get product ID no matter what is the number after i: . Is there something like echo $rslt[x]['product_id']; where x is number between 0-9?

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble before unserializing data that had been serialized and saved to a database. The easiest way I found to sort it was base64_encode on serialize and decode on unserialize.

`$seralized_data = base64_encode(serialize($data));`

`$unserialized_data = unserialize(base64_decode($data));`

Comment: What this guy says. `serialize()` can produce funky non-printing characters in the output, such as the 'null' character or `\0`, which do not play nicely with the other kids like mySQL and some I/O functions. Using `base64_encode()` like @Qoop suggests will ensure that the data is preserved as-is, and does not disrupt other functions.

Comment: I should have added that if you need to be able to 'see' the stored object for a query or whatnot you can use the `json_encode()/decode()` functions instead of serialize as they don't seem to produce any strange control characters.